# Romberg-Integration relative error

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

How can I check if the relative error of two successive diagonal elements is smaller than e.g. $10^{-3}$?

$\left\vert \frac{T_{1,2}-T_{1,3}}{T_{1,3}}\right\vert<0.001$

for a Romberg Tableau of this form

$\begin{array}{cccccc}
T_{1,1}\\
&\backslash\\
T_{2,2}&-&T_{1,2}\\
&\backslash&&\backslash\\
T_{3,3}&-&T_{2,3}&-&T_{1,3}\\
&\backslash&&\backslash&&\backslash\\
\end{array}$

I am using for $h=\frac{b-a}{N_i}$ with $a$, $b$ as integral limits and $N_i=2^i$, $i=1,...$ as Romberg sequence.

I am using the trapezoidal sum to compute

$T_{i,1}=T(h_i)=\frac{h_i}{2}\left(f(a)+f(b)+\sum_{j=1}^{N_i-1}f(a+j\cdot h_i)\right)$

and all other elements are computed with the following formula:

$T_{(j,j+k)}(f)=T_{(j+1,j+k)}(f)+\frac{T_{(j+1,k+1)}(f)-T_{(j,j+k-1)}(f)}{\left(\frac{h_j}{h_{j+k}}\right)^2-1}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the trapezoidal and what the Simpson sums? Are these the diagonals? Is the difference that you want to estimate between trapezoidal sums?

Comment: I think/hope I added all the missing information.